# not able to catch org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException in Service or Facade Layer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, concurrency

```
public class AccountServiceFacade {

public void updateAccount(Account accnt) {
    try {
        getAccountService.updateAccount();
     }
    catch(HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}



public class AccountService {

public void updateAccount(Account accnt) {
    try {
     getAccountDAO().getHibernateTemplate().update(accnt);
    System.out.println("Updated sucessfully");
    } catch(HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I have AccountServiceFacade in transaction.
In AccountServiceFacade also my flow is not coming to catch block.
Only i am getting the exception in presentation layer that is Action class.
But i need to send a user defined message by depending on the exception comes.
So how can i get the exception in sevicefacade layer or service layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to catch StaleObjectStateException or StaleStateException at this point. 
But as you said you already have an exception in presentation layer why just not use it?

Comment: But in presentation layer, i can't get this "StaleObjectStateException "

Comment: I can directly use RuntimeException in my catch block. But i want to show a specific message if concurrency fails.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
    catch (Exception e) {
                if(e instanceof StaleStateException || e instanceof OptimisticLockingFailureException || e instanceof HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException || e instanceof org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException) {
                             some code
                }
     }
```